# Css - Can't change vertical position on <a> tag

Tags: css, tags

At my [website](http://mmd3e12dae42.keaweb.dk/test/index.html) i want to move the a tag(the black box) down to the middle, but i cant get it to work. I must not affect the other elements on the page.
When i add top: 50%; in firebug it moves down to middle as i want it to, but i can't make it work for the real site.
The CSS for the element:

```
.section {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;    
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 720px;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `display: inline-block` to your `.selection` so it correctly renders out the height of the element.

But now on to your real problem: You could use: `top: 450px`

Comment: sorry my fault. I must have made a typo when i first tested your suggestion. It works in all browsers when defined in pixels. Weird that the webkit browsers doesn't support % in this way.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that your a tag is properly nested in another element ( div, p, etc) and set the position of that element with CSS.

```
<div class="sectionhldr" >
      <a class="section" href="/*destination*/"> My Link</a>
</div>
```

set the position to the div class.

Comment: I just found out it actually works in Firefox, but not in safari and chrome.. how can that be?

Comment: could you add some code? What have you changed for FF to get it working?

Comment: I put top: 50%; like i did in firebug. But it won't work in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
.section {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: I need to have one <a> tag on each page as it registers which page im on. Absolute put them all on the first page on top of each others.

Comment: @McKeene the same <a>? I've reverted to relative which seems to work however, you may have to add individual styles for the .story elements for the ones you want on the left and on the right. Floating the stories (left/right) seemed to work rather than the inner elements.

Comment: This sadly gives me the same problem. It works great in firefox, but in safari and chrome its still on the top of each page :(